# How do I access the data sent over UDP?

Tags: rust

[Looking at the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from), I can only find a way to return the size of the content sent over UDP:

> Receives data from the socket. On success, returns the number of bytes read and the address from whence the data came.

Is there currently a way to output the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn recv_from(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>
```

The data is read into the start of `buf`. Thus, the data read can be accessed as a `&[u8]` like so:

```
match socket.recv_from(buf) {
    Ok((bytes_read, _)) => Some(&buf[0..bytes_read]),
    Err(_) => None,
}
```